# Get only the name attribute of the variable send from controller

Tags: laravel

I have this code below:

```
 <script  type="text/javascript">
        var rtypes = {!!  $registration_type !!}       
</script>
```

With this in the source code it appears:

```
var rtypes = [{"id":1,"name":"general","description":"description geral","capacity":100},{"id":2,"name":"plus","description":"description plus","capacity":10}]
```

But I would like to have only the registration type names like "['general', 'plus', ...];"

Do you know how to get only the name attribute in the JS?

**Method that returns the view:**

```
 public function edit($id)
    {
        $conf = Conf::find($id);
        $registrationType = RegistrationType::where('conf_id', $id)->get();
        return view('questions.edit')
            ->with('registration_type', $registrationType)
    }
```

Comment: `$registrationType = RegistrationType::where('conf_id', $id)->get()->pluck('name');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use method `pluck()`

Here is an example

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        $conf = Conf::find($id);
        $registrationType = RegistrationType::where('conf_id', $id)->get()
       ->pluck('name');
        return view('questions.edit')
            ->with('registration_type', $registrationType)
    }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: exactly six seconds

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [pluck](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-pluck) method:

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $conf = Conf::find($id);
    $registrationTypes = RegistrationType::where('conf_id', $id)->get();
    $registrationType = $registrationTypes->pluck('name');
    return view('questions.edit')
        ->with('registration_type', $registrationType)
}
```

Variable naming is not really good here, but this way you don't need to change any of your code.